# How to see and kill running Grails servers

Tags: eclipse, grails, ubuntu

So I've been using the command `-Dserver.port=8081 run-app` to run my Grails apps through that port on my local machine.  But it seems like every time I start a server up I can't restart it because it continues to run on that port.  So I'll end up switching to some other port, like 8082, until I need to start it again...which is starting to seem a bit of a silly way to do things.

I did a quick google search to try and find a simple way to see if I have a Grails server open on a port, but I can't seem to figure it out.  So I was wondering, does anyone know of a way to quickly see a list of running Grails servers and then an equally quick way to kill those servers so I can run more code on the same port?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm really hoping there is a Grails command for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal then type

```
ps -aux |grep grails
```

it shows all the grail running processes, like

[image]

And for killing a process

```
kill -9 XXX
```

where XXX is grails server process id(5198 in my case, as in image).

Note: add sudo if you are running server in root.(I am using ubuntu)

Comment: So, there's no Grails command to just show the servers it is running?

Comment: I am not sure whether there is any grails command exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `_GrailsRun.groovy` script has a check for a kill file, which if it exists will shut down a Grails run-app instance.  The file's name is `.kill-run-app` and should be placed at the root of your Grails project.  The file is deleted by the run-app script, so if multiple Grails instances are running the file may have to be created multiple times.